# Докер постоянно перезапускает загрузку файла для ML

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

Ребята, помогите разобраться с Докером, пожалуйста.

Пробую запустить ML через Докер.

Вижу, что модель пробует скачать 3Гб файл, но доходит до 18% и скидывает обратно и пробует заново качать и так по кругу.

Лог с Докера:

```
Downloading:  16%|█▌        | 504M/3.14G [00:22<01:58, 22.2MB/s]
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:08:14 +0000] [97] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 97
Downloading:  18%|█▊        | 564M/3.14G [00:22<01:34, 27.3MB/s][2021-07-31 20:08:44 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:97)
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:08:44 +0000] [97] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 97)
Downloading:  18%|█▊        | 566M/3.14G [00:22<01:42, 25.1MB/s]
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:08:45 +0000] [102] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 102
Downloading:   2%|▏         | 71.1M/3.14G [00:22<19:04, 2.68MB/s][2021-07-31 20:09:15 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:102)
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:09:15 +0000] [102] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 102)
Downloading:   2%|▏         | 71.3M/3.14G [00:22<16:19, 3.13MB/s]
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:09:16 +0000] [107] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 107
Downloading:   6%|▌         | 175M/3.14G [00:22<01:54, 25.9MB/s][2021-07-31 20:09:46 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:107)
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:09:46 +0000] [107] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 107)
Downloading:   6%|▌         | 178M/3.14G [00:22<06:18, 7.83MB/s]
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:09:47 +0000] [112] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 112
Downloading:  18%|█▊        | 553M/3.14G [00:22<01:44, 24.8MB/s][2021-07-31 20:10:17 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:112)
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:10:17 +0000] [112] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 112)
Downloading:  18%|█▊        | 554M/3.14G [00:22<01:46, 24.4MB/s]
api_1  | [2021-07-31 20:10:17 +0000] [117] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 117
```

Нагрузка Докером сервера:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                 CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O     PIDS
43e8b99ef3cd   bg_rugpt3_xl_api_1   21.75%    496.3MiB / 15.27GiB   3.17%     6.54GB / 11.6MB   52.5MB / 0B   6
```

И нагрузка сервера из htop:

```
1  [                                                      0.0%]   Tasks: 45, 80 thr; 1 running
  2  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   Load average: 0.54 0.67 1.82 
  3  [                                                      0.0%]   Uptime: 2 days, 02:16:02
  4  [                                                      0.0%]
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||             563M/15.3G]
  Swp[                                                     0K/0K]

    PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
      1 root       20   0  164M  6416  2272 S  0.0  0.0  1:40.57 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 30
    529 root       20   0  230M   912     0 S  0.0  0.0  3:09.93 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
    532 root       20   0  6812   936   668 S  0.0  0.0  0:12.21 /usr/sbin/cron -f
    533 messagebu  20   0  7620  1428   516 S  0.0  0.0  0:02.13 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --
    534 root       20   0  230M   912     0 S  0.0  0.0  3:09.68 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
    545 root       20   0 81928   340     0 S  0.0  0.0  3:53.83 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
    550 root       20   0 81928   340     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
    553 syslog     20   0  219M  2008     0 S  0.0  0.0  1:26.82 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
    554 root       20   0 16720   928     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:04.94 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
    556 daemon     20   0  3792   188     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.02 /usr/sbin/atd -f
    559 syslog     20   0  219M  2008     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:13.03 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
```

Такой Докер-файл:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7

# clean and update sources
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/bg_rugpt3_xl

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm
#RUN python -m deeppavlov install syntax_ru_syntagrus_bert

# copy project
COPY . .
```

Ну и Докер-компоус:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000
    volumes:
      - ./model:/usr/src/bsg_antispam/ml_model/pretrained_model
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - 8081:5000
```

Comment: Если worker timeout - значит увеличьте этот самый таймаут в настройках gunicorn

Comment: Точно. Запустилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил timeout для gunicorn:

```yaml
command: gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 1200 --worker-class=gthread
```